# Is it possible to set up multiple wake up interrupts on STM32. ? How to manage multiple sensor reading intervals?

Tags: sensor, stm32, low-power, sleep, mems

I am new to developing applications on STM32 development boards.
Currently i have STM32 IoT discovery kit. I am able to configure all the sensors and read data. I am interested in low power design especially STOP2 mode, when i can retain all the variables on SRAM. I want to achieve low power consumption keeping sensor reading intervals low. Imagine having 3 different sensors, reading sensor data at 3 diffrent intervals for e.g.

1. Sensor A - read every 15mins
2. Sensor B - read every 30mins
3. sensor C - read every hour.

So far i have implemented a storing mechanism to store data. I have also implemented the stop2 mode sample which wakeup every 33seconds (from examples). How can i achieve functionality where i can read/poll at diffrent intervals and keep the MCU in stop2 mode after the reading is finished.?

Answer (score 2):

This is a trivial software problem. You keep "time to next wake-up" per each sensor. On every wake-up you subtract elapsed time from every value, measure sensors that reached zero (and re-initialize their counters with corresponding sampling periods) and at the same time find the smallest value of the rest. Setup your timer to wake-up after this smallest period and activate sleep again.

You only need one wake-up source for this to work. It can be RTC alarm, low-power timer or even WDT timer, depending on what is available on your MCU in chosen sleep mode. This method will work even if longest possible sleep period is shorter than smallest required delay. In this case you simply subtract elapsed time without polling any sensors and go into next sleep period immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to go about this, but there are probably more :

- You could keep the timer at a fixed interval and increment a counter each time it wakes up. If the timer runs for 30 seconds and you want a measurement every 2 minutes and another every 4 minutes, that means you will make the measurements every 4 and 8 wakeups respectively. But I fear this solution is not the most power-efficient, since you will need to wake up more often.
- You can set up alarms on the real-time clock at a specific timestamp, and these alarms should be able to generate an interrupt to wake up the processor. Look up RTC alarm in the datasheets/application notes.

Comment: I was looking at the first option which you mentioned, it also occured to me that i will have wake up more often depending on the nimber of sensors enabled. According to your second option suggested, does it mean that I should configure 3 different alarms for 3 different sensors ? Given that the polling interval for each sensor is different.

Comment: Depending on your model of STM32, you might only have one or two different alarms available. Also, I think you will need to set the timestamp again each time the alarm fires, like (current time + interval). This new interval could maybe be calculated to take into account two or more sensors.